# Trying to sum a column, but only if the value corresponds to a value in another column (excel doc imported to Jupyter)

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am importing a sheet from Excel, and trying to sum the columns but filter them based on another column.

So, using the picture for reference, I would like the sum of the R-AMT column, but only for those cells in the 'HIT' column with a 'Done' value.

I am very new to coding, so I don't have many examples. I have tried the `groupby` function but it returned both Done and Away values, which wasn't useful.

```
hit_volume = df.groupby('HIT')[['R-AMT']].sum()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: Excel Data I am using]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['HIT'] == 'Done', 'R-AMT'].sum()
```

Comment: I don't know you, but thank you. I am forever in your debt, internet stranger.